# For loop causing error in Junit with Selenium while searching data in a column

Tags: java

i m getting error for my following for loop in junit3

```
    for(int i=9;i<=58;i++)
    {
    x = selenium.getTable("//table[4].".i.".6");
    if(x == "single" || x = "OneToMany")
        {   
            found="true";
        }
        else 
        break;
        }
```

can someone solve my problem where i m going wrong
Thanks in advance

Comment: *"i m getting error.."*  What error?  Copy/paste it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this code really Java code?

As @matt-ball already said, instead of

```
if(x == "single" || x = "OneToMany")
```

should be

```
if ("single".equals(x) || "OneToMany".equals(x))
```

Note, that in Java you should not compare String with `==`, but should use `equals()` instead.

Also following code looks strange for me:

```
x = selenium.getTable("//table[4].".i.".6");
```

Is this string concatenation? It looks like PHP code. A think in Java this should be like this:

```
x = selenium.getTable("//table[4]." + i + ".6");
```

or

```
x = selenium.getTable("//table[4]." + String.valueOf(i) + ".6");
```

or

```
x = selenium.getTable(String.format("//table[4].%d.6", i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's because you're assigning `x`.

```
x = "OneToMany"
```